# How to Add an Empty, Unbound, Comment Column to a GridView?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've put together a GridView table in ASP.net that allows users to approve a series of records. As part of this approval process, I'd like to provide an empty column for the user to provide comments where necessary. The only records showing up will be records that haven't been approved yet, thus, no comments will need to be loaded. Once they are approved, users will not be able to view these records again.

How do I go about adding this empty column to my GridView? Again, there's no data to load into this column. Once approved, the records in the SQL Server table will be updated with a timestamp and comments.

Most of what I was able to find on here so far has been related to adding empty rows, but not columns. I'm completely new to ASP.net, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Current Column Code:

```
asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" ItemStyle-Width="500px" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" SortExpression="Comment" /
```

Comment: use a `TemplateField` with no content.

Comment: Right now, I've set it up as a template field, but I'm unable to click in the box and add a comment.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but it sound to me that you want to edit/update inside the templatefield. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: That seems like it's close to what I'm looking for, but would it be possible to enter text into the comment field WITHOUT making the user clicking an edit button? I was hoping that they'd be able to click directly in the box and type away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple solution I've quickly put together. It uses the `OnRowCommand` event of the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("textfield") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UpdateButton">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a gridview
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;

    //cast the commandsource back to a button
    Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button;

    //cast the namingcontainer of the button back to a gridviewrow
    GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //find the correct textbox using findcontrol and the index obtained from the row
    TextBox tb = gv.Rows[row.DataItemIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

    //show result
    Label1.Text = tb.Text;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or if you want to update all the records at once by pressing a button.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox tb = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        Label1.Text += tb.Text + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: The text box looks great. Is the rest of this necessary if I already have a process in place to update the records? Will the page temporarily store the comments in each box until the user clicks the 'Submit' button?

I have a button at the bottom that runs a vb script that iterates through each row, updating the data based on user selections for each row, the idea being that I would update all of the records in one process rather than update them one at a time.

Comment: That will work also. This example uses an update button per row.

Comment: What would happen if the update button were not present, but the textbox was? Running the FULL update for all records at the end and skipping the individual button presses, would those comments make it to my update statement if stored in a variable during the evaluation of each line?

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm asking conceptually, would assigning the value to a variable in the ForEach loop successfully pass the value? I like the idea of a single button press MUCH more than all of those individual clicks, but it does look like there's some added lag caused by the use of Eval. Because of that lag, I may not be able to make use of this for my current project, but it's certainly interesting.

Comment: Yes it would. Just as you can read the text you can also update it.